# Dynamically add year variable to meta title / description in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, variables, meta-title, meta-description

I am trying to automatically add the current year to the meta title and description in for example category-pages. I want to achieve something like this:

Meta title: "The best category items for **{{year}}**" >> "The best category items for **2019**"

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: for a particular category or all categories?

Comment: For all categories in which the {{year}} tag is used. I just want to replace this tag with the current year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use event/observer.

Fire an observer on the event  `catalog_category_load_after` at frontend area set meta description on the fly.

> Create `events.xml` at 
>   `app/code/StackExchange/Magento/etc/frontend/` and as
>   `events.xml location under on **frontend** and this event only fire
>   for frontend area.

### events.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_load_after">
        <observer instance="StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\CategoryLoadAfter" 
                  name="stackexchange_magento_observer_frontend_catalog_categoryloadafter_catalog_product_load_after"
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Create Observer  class `CategoryLoadAfter` at 
>   `app/code/StackExchange/Magento/Observer/Frontend/Catalog/`.

### CategoryLoadAfter.php code

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend\Catalog;

class CategoryLoadAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
     \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__);
        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
        if ($category instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category) {
            $oldMetaTitle = $category->getMetaTitle();
            $oldMetaDescription = $category->getMetaDescription();
            $oldMetaKeyword = $category->getMetaKeywords();
            $category->setMetaTitle(str_replace("{{year}}",date('Y'),$oldMetaTitle));
            $category->setMetaDescription(str_replace("{{year}}",date('Y'),$oldMetaDescription));
            $category->setMetaKeywords(str_replace("{{year}}",date('Y'),$oldMetaKeyword));
        }
    }

}
```

### Also, your module must have:

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.php`

**After adding the event you should  flush the cache.**

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great!

Comment: How could set the month and year, for example {{month}} {{year}}

Comment: I figured it out date('F Y'), but what if I want to use the month and year separately for some meta titles. For example "offers for {{month}}" or "best sales of {{year}}", or combination "best offer for {{month}} {{year}}"

Comment: yes, you can what you want. Just change require a value  at respective method like `setMetaTitle`

Comment: sorry, but how do I do that?

Comment: I fugured it out, - `$placeholder  = array("{{year}}", "{{month}}");
            $values = array(date('Y'), date('F'));
            $category->setMetaTitle(str_replace($placeholder, $values,$oldMetaTitle));`